# Thrust not calling device function

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have following simple CUDA-Thrust code which adds 10 to device vector but the function is getting called on host side instead of device.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

__host__ __device__ int add(int x){
    #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
     printf("In device\n");
    #else
     printf("In host\n");
    #endif

    return x+10;
}

int main(void)
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> H(4);
    H[0] = H[1] = H[2] = H[3] = 10;

    thrust::device_vector<int> data=H;

    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),add);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The address of a `__device__` or `__host__ __device__` function (`add`) cannot be taken by a `__host__ ` function (`main`). Use a function object (for example, `thrust::plus<int>`) instead of a free function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) has good examples to follow.

It looks like you have several issues, some already pointed out.

1. If you want to use thrust, you should use `thrust::transform`, not `std::transform`.  `std::transform` has no knowledge of the GPU or CUDA or thrust, and will dispatch the host version of your `add` function. I'm not sure what that would do exactly when you pass a `thrust::device_vector` to it.
2. Thrust algorithms need to use function objects (functors) rather than bare CUDA `__device__` functions, for the reason indicated by Jared (the thrust algorithm in your source code is actually host code.  That host code cannot discover the address of a bare `__device__` function).  With this fix, you can be pretty certain that thrust will dispatch the device code path when working on device vectors.

Here's a modification of your code:

```
$ cat t856.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

struct my_func {

__host__ __device__
  int operator()(int x){
    #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
     printf("In device, x is %d\n", x);
    #else
     printf("In host, x is %d\n", x);
    #endif

    return x+10;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> H(4);
    H[0] = H[1] = H[2] = H[3] = 10;

    thrust::device_vector<int> data=H;

    thrust::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),my_func());
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t856 t856.cu
$ ./t856
In device, x is 10
In device, x is 10
In device, x is 10
In device, x is 10
$
```